# Siamese network using VGG16 to verify the similarity images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I want to create a deep learning model which verify the similarity of the images. So, I will use Siamese network. My dataset is images dataset not CSV file.

How can I create a Siamese network using VGG16 in Keras?